# TypeScript - Using Generics to Create a Custom Type

Tags: typescript

I'm using an intermediary step for creating a **type** that has property keys that must be the same as the keys of a specified **interface**

```js
// 1. Create Interface
interface IDetail {
    name: string;
    enabled: boolean;
}

// 2. Create a 'type' that has properties that match the properties of an interface
type DetailType = {
    [key in keyof IDetail]: any
}

// 3. Apply the type to an object literal
const control: DetailType = {
    name: [],
    enabled: []
}
```

I repeat this pattern quite often, and I'm wondering is there a way to generalize the 2nd step - possibly using **generics**?

Comment: What is the purpose of the type? Since you map it to `any` you lose type information..

Comment: Is `Record<keyof Interface, any>` a thing you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a special generic type:

```
type WrapMyType<T, V> = { [key in keyof T]: V };

const control: WrapMyType<IDetail, any> = {
  name: [],
  enabled: [],
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can just make your type generic:

```
interface IDetail {
  name: string;
  enabled: boolean;
}

type Generic<T> = { [key in keyof T]: any };

const controlGeneric: Generic<IDetail> = {
  name: [],
  enabled: []
};
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to lose the types you can use this approach

```
type DetailType<T> = { [key in keyof T]: T[key] };

const control: DetailType<IDetail> = {
    name: [], // must be string
    enabled: [] // must be boolean
}
```